# Vuforia makes mesh not render when object not on camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have two gameObject attached on Vuforia's images. One of them is a "monitor", that contains a plane with a Render texture.

This render texture shows what a camera attached to the other component is seeing in the game-view (with skybox ecc).

In AR when both images are on camera, the screen shows the other object.
As soon as the "focus object" is pulled out, the camera shows only the skybox.

Vuforia doesn't render anything that is out of the AR-camera, but is there some work-around?

[monitor and object on camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYSiA.jpg)

[object pulled out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGSvP.jpg)